# How to move button from his current position

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I need to do task where arrow key moves button(BUTTON!). I stuck on one final step. I don't know method(if there is any) to move my button instead of some accurate place in window just few pixels up, down, left or right.

I did every function for each key as you can see in my code. As you can see I tried probably stupid thing...to increment positio(x) by one each time key is pressed but..it doesn't work.

```
import tkinter as tk

def up(event):
    if event:
        button.place(x=x+1)


def down(event):
    if event:
        print("Down")

def left(event):
    if event:
        print("Left")
def right(event):
    if event:
        print("Right")



window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
button = tk.Button(master=window, bitmap="questhead")
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center",)
button.focus_set()
button.bind("<Up>", up)
button.bind("<Down>", down)
button.bind("<Left>", left)
button.bind("<Right>", right)

window.mainloop()
```

What I want achieve is..when I press up arrow my button moves 1px up when I press down it moves 1px down etc.

Comment: *"want ... when ... up arrow ... moves 1px up"*: use `button.place(y=int(button.place_info()['y']) - 1)`. Read [Tkinter.Place.place_info-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm#Tkinter.Place.place_info-method)

Comment: Thank You so much!!! :)